# Set default value for selectbox

Tags: python, streamlit

I am new to streamlit.
I tried to set a default value for sidebar.selectbox.
The code is below.
I appreciate the help!
Thank you in advance.

```
st.sidebar.header('Settings')

fichier = st.sidebar.selectbox('Dataset', ('djia', 'msci', 'nyse_n', 'nyse_o', 'sp500', 'tse'))

window_ANTICOR = st.sidebar.selectbox('Window ANTICOR', ['<select>',3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30])
if window_ANTICOR == '<select>':    
    window_ANTICOR == 30

window_OLMAR = st.sidebar.selectbox('Window OLMAR', ['<select>',3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30])
if window_OLMAR == '<select>':    
    window_OLMAR == 5

eps_OLMAR = st.sidebar.selectbox('Eps OLMAR', ['<select>', 3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30])
if eps_OLMAR == '<select>':    
    eps_OLMAR == 10

eps_PAMR = st.sidebar.selectbox('Eps PAMR', ['<select>',0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1])
if eps_PAMR == '<select>':    
    eps_PAMR == 0.5

variant = st.sidebar.selectbox('Variant PAMR', (0, 1, 2))
if variant == '<select>':    
    eps_PAMR == 0
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `index` keyword of the `selectbox` widget. Pass the index of the value in the `options` list that you want to be the default choice.

E.g. if you wanted to set the default choice of the selectbox labeled `'Window ANTICOR'` to 30 (which you appear to be trying to do), you could simply do this:

```
values = ['<select>',3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30]
default_ix = values.index(30)
window_ANTICOR = st.sidebar.selectbox('Window ANTICOR', values, index=default_ix)
```

Source: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.selectbox

Answer (score 2):

you can directly give index also for default position

bins = st.sidebar.radio(label="Category :", options=n3, index=0)
for more information
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WemYUhOazM&list=PLWpRmFIFIDaGIo8nAywmsPeDLb4vDtCGn)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32595048)

Answer (score 1):

```
values = ['Select', 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
default_ix = values.index(10)
if values == 'Select':
    st.warning("Choose the integers from the list in the dropdown")
else:
    components = st.selectbox("Select the components below⤵️", values, 
    index=default_ix)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).