# Streamlit filter county dropdown based on state chosen

Tags: streamlit

In my code once the user chooses the state from the first dropdown, I want to display counties only from that state in the second dropdown. Currently it always filters the county to Alaska which is the first state listed in the state dropdown.

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

st.sidebar.info('### ***US States and Counties***')
    
with st.sidebar:
    # Add a dropdown to select a state
    state_county_data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kjhealy/us-county/master/data/census/fips-by-state.csv",encoding = 'unicode_escape')
    states = sorted(state_county_data["state"].unique())
    selected_state = st.selectbox("Select a state", states)

    # Use the state code to filter the counties dataframe
    counties = sorted(state_county_data.loc[state_county_data["state"] == selected_state]["name"].unique())

    # Add a dropdown to select a county
    selected_county = st.selectbox("Select a county", counties)

    # Show the selected state and county
    button = st.button('Update')
```

Comment: I tried your code and it is happening as intended: when you select a state, it only shows counties from that state. By default, when first loading the page, it shows "AK" and the counties of "Alaska" but you can choose a different default value. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65145404/5446749

Comment: I had to upgrade my streamlit version and then it started working, thanks for testing

Comment: what version did you have?